# svn repository in a local repository

Tags: eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn, subclipse

i work with my train mate in a local network, so we want to make the server our repository where we commit and check out ina directory on it.
so if there is any ability to set a directory in our server as our svn repositry, then email me the solution or send me the web reference where i can find the solution.
i work with subversion and turtoise.(note i also work with subclipse under eclipse).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Subversion checkouts are local** on your PC. So you can do a checkout, all the files are on your PC, you can edit them offline, and when you go online again you can commit them. (This does not mean that you and your mate can collaberate without both having access to the server, however).

Subversion repositories are **very often URLs**. In which case, you can send those URLs around, you can open them in the browser (to see the files, although the interface is pretty basic admittedly.)

In any case, **all subversion repository identifiers are strings** (even those that aren't URLs) so you can definitely send them via email, etc., and use a Subversion client e.g. TortoiseSVN to view/checkout the repositories.